# Something similar to Gource, but more general visualisations of SVO relations over time?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a set of data which records events that happen between subjects and objects (in the RDF sense) over time. E.g. "entity X pinged entity Y at this datetime", such as:

- this webpage linked to this webpage at this time
- this person talked to this person at this time

I plugged this into Gource and got a nice visualisation, but the graphics are oriented towards individual Xes (people) and a hierarchical Y (source tree). My data is non-hierarchical and the domains of subjects and objects aren't disjoint (whereas in Gource the set of files and the set of contributes are disjoint).

Is there anything similar to Gource that visualises the relationships between entities over time? I'm asking recommendation of a visualisation, so I can't pre-judge the kind of output it gives.

Requirements:

- runs on GNU/Linux or Mac OS or web
- ingests data in a subject-verb-object, time format

Input format isn't important.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question supplying, I hope, enough info. I'm not pre-judging any answers -- I know about the kind of the input data; I don't know about the desired format of the result, hence the question.

Comment: Thanks, Joe – I'd say the basics are there. If someone has something in mind and needs specific clarification, I'd expect him/her to put another comment. Just made space for that now :)